# Google Sheets formula that queries recurring data based on time interval/frequency

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to have a calendar display a series of activities based on their type, time and frequency for an easier visualization of data.

So far, I have managed to create a formula that correctly fetches the data that I have on a repository and displays it on the calendar. However, I'm not sure how I can have it account for entries that have a frequency (happening every x days).

For an easier understanding here are screenshots of both the table and the schedule
[image: table]

[image: schedule]

And here's the current formula I'm using to display the event/activity title in each day/hour at C12 for example:

```
=IFERROR(
    INDEX(Repository!$K:$K, 
        MATCH(
            C$10, 
            IF(
                (Repository!$G:$G=$G$8)*
                (Repository!$H:$H=$K$8)*
                (Repository!$N:$N>=$B12)*
                (Repository!$N:$N<$B12+TIME(2,0,0)),
               Repository!$D:$D),
            0)
         ),
      "")
```

What I'm currently missing on the formula is a way to correctly account for the start/end date as well as frequency and understand if each day falls under the specified criteria. In case the frequency is 0 then I'd like to have it discard the end date at all (in case for some reason I end up forgetting to set the end date).

I have tried to work with the formula provided to account for the frequency but nothing that I tried seemed to work.

### **Minimal example**

Entry on the table with a 2 days frequency:
[image: entry table]

Expected result on the schedule:
[image: entry schedule]

So basically, the formula on each cell should check for the start date, end date and frequency of the activity and identify if the specific date on the schedule falls under the specified timeframe.

In this minimal example, the activity starts on the 7th December and repeats every 2 days until the 14th of December.

**Feel free to duplicate the spreadsheet here:**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19h0v3XjDqa_DWSx-QBGBNwFGd550a_D3DVFovs5s2qo/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried to build the formula in multiple ways but I can't seem to make it count for the time frequency so that cells recognize this and display the activity in any other dates besides the initial one.

Comment: is frequency just a linear distribution within a time frame window (from start to end date)?

Comment: @player0 Exactly - If the start day is 01/01/2023 and end date is 31/01/2023 and the frequency 7 days it means that the activity will repeat every 7 days starting on the 01/01 until the 31/01. So it would repeat itself 5 times (the last one being on 29/01).

Comment: what about test#2? in repo you have it on 11:00 but on schedule you got only 10:00 and 12:00

Answer (score 0):

delete all your formulae and use this in C6:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(TEXT(C4:P4+B6:B14, "e-m-d-h-m")&G$2&K$2, SPLIT(FLATTEN(MAP(
 Repository!D$4:D, Repository!O$4:O, Repository!P$4:P, Repository!N$4:N, 
 Repository!G$4:G, Repository!H$4:H, Repository!K$4:K, LAMBDA(d, o, p, n, g, h, k, 
 IF(DAYS(o, d)>=SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(o, d)), 0, p), TEXT(d+SEQUENCE(1, 
 MAX(DAYS(o, d)), 0, p)+IF(ISODD(HOUR(n)), (HOUR(n)*"1:00")-"1:00", HOUR(n)*"1:00"), 
 "e-m-d-h-m")&g&h&"×"&k, )))), "×"), 2, )))
```

then copy C6 and paste in C18, C30, etc.

[image]